# How to use OnGetPassword send password for establishing SSL connection in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7, indy10

I'm trying to establish a SSL connection from Delphi to a Webservice. But to send the password, I could find that OnGetPassword function must be used. But I couldn't get any information on how to use this function. Saw the below function. But this just gives undeclared indentifier during compilation

```
procedure TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1GetPassword(var Password: string);
begin
  Password := 'thepassword';
end;
```

Can anyone please shed some light on how should I use this function to send the password. Below is my code (just the SSL part)

```
        Id_HandlerSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create(nil);
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'CARootcert.pem';
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'clicert.pem';
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'clikey.pem';
        Id_HandlerSocket.OnGetPassword := GetPassword; // Needs to be corrected
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
type
  TForm1 = Class(TForm)
     function GetPassword : String;
  end;

function TForm1.GetPassword : String;
begin
  Result := 'Thepassword';
end;

Id_HandlerSocket.OnGetPassword := GetPassword; //Just the part calling the proc
```

But on compiling, I get the error - Undeclared identifier - GetPassword.

How should I access the function GetPassword ?

Comment: It so confuse, what is assign to the event? method interface or class method instance?

Comment: First, your `GetPassword()` method has the wrong signature for the `OnGetPassword` event. It needs to be declared as `procedure GetPassword(var Password: String);` instead. Second, you did not show WHERE you are creating `Id_HandlerSocket` from, but clearly it is not inside a method of `Form1` or else you would not be getting an "Undeclared identifier" error. Third, the `OnGetPassword` event is for providing a password when loading a password-protected certificate, not for accessing a password-protected server. That is a completely different thing. So, what EXACTLY do you need a password for?

Comment: The unit from where the web service is called does not have a FORM. I used  ```procedure GetPasword(var Password:String);```                           But still gets the undeclared identifier in ```Id_HandlerSocket.OnGetPassword := GetPassword; ```. About your second point, Id_HandlerSocket is created in the same function from where OnGetPassword is called (you can see this in my post above). What I understand is I should define another method in TForm1 and do the creation of Id_HandlerSocket in that. Then I will be able to access GetPassword in OnGetPassword. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Also, about your 3rd question, I'm trying to send the password for client certificate file to the server using OnGetPassword.

Comment: @SanyoAlexis what you have shown is not a [mcve], so it is difficult to address your issues. As for the password itself, you clearly don't understand how they work. A client certificate password is not sent to the server. That is not what the `OnGetPassword` is meant for, and that is not how SSL/TLS works.